Symmetrizing an armature not working
I'm trying to rig a model for animating but I can't finish the Armature as it refuses to Symmetrize. I've applied rotation, scale and location, also tried putting the mesh on a different axis, but nothing worked.
I'm also following a tutorial. I don't know what I'm doing wrong for it to not work
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ANa_V1mc9E&t=2s&ab_channel=RyanGames

and also, here's the .blend file


That's a very quick and dirty tutorial I would suggest finding something that's a little more thorough, as the video makes no mention of naming the bones or what direction the armature should be facing, your armature was facing the side and bones were unnamed.

Orientate the character to facing the front view so it symmetrizes along the X axis and named the bones appropriately with a "L" for left or "R" for right depending on which side your starting with.
Select the bones you want to symmetrize and Blender will duplicate and rename those bones for the other half of the armature.



Hey for some reason it refuses to symmetrize properly. Every time I press Symmetrize, it creates a copy on top of the already existing armatures, not on the side I want it on. I did give them proper names as well, and I also put the mesh with its armature on the X axis too

@prox-ee The symmetry will happen on the X axis, make sure that your armature is correctly oriented and also apply the rotation (Ctrl A)

I can't believe I forgot about applying rotation. Sorry about that. Also it worked! Thanks!
